# Replace all spaces in a string with underscores

Tags: python

How would I replace the spaces in a string with underscores without using the replace function. I was told to also use a accumulation string with some type of loop

```
string = input("Enter a string")
i = 0
acc = ""

for char in string:
    if char == " ":
        acc = string + "_"

print(acc)
```

Comment: You must append to `acc` not to `string`. and you need an else clause to append the `char` unchanged if it isn't a space.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
string = input("Enter a string")
i = 0
acc = ""
newlist = [] #create a new list which will be the output
strlist = list(string) #create a list of each character in the input string
for char in strlist:
    if char == " ":
        newlist.append('_')
    newlist.append(char)    
acc = ''.join(newlist)
print(acc)
```

Comment: Im not allowed use the .replace function

Answer (score 0):

Your code should to be :

```
string = input("Enter a string")
i = 0
acc = ""

for char in string:
    if char == " ":
        acc += "_"
    else:
        acc += char

print(acc)
```

Try it if without `replace`.

```
string = input("Enter a string")
res = ''.join(["_" if i == " " else i for i in string])
print(res)
```

Another method:

```
string = input("Enter a string")
res = "_".join(string.split(" "))
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use `split`, then

```
s = 'Your string with spaces'

s_ = '' 
for word in s.split():
    s_ += '_' + word

s_[1:]  # 'Your_string_with_spaces'
```

Otherwise, instead of words, concatenate characters with '_' instead of ' ':

```
s_ = '' 
for char in s:
    if char == ' ':
        s_ += '_'
    else:
        s_ += char
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't too far off. You can use an accumulation string like this:

```
string = input("Enter a string")
acc = ""
for char in string:
    if char == " ":
        char = "_"
    acc += char

print(acc)
```